# Update the input of a loop with a result from the previous iteration of the loop

Tags: python, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

(I've added the google-analytics api tags but I suspect that my issue is more a fundamental flaw in my approach to a loop, detailed below)

I'm using Python to query the Google Analytics API (V4). Having already successfully connected to the API with my credentials, I'm trying to loop over each 10k result set returned by the API to get the full results set.

When querying the API you pass a dict that looks something like this:

```
{'reportRequests':[{'viewId': '1234567', # my actual view id goes here of course
    'pageToken': 'go', # can be any string initially (I think?)
    'pageSize': 10000,
    'samplingLevel': 'LARGE',
    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2018-06-01', 'endDate': '2018-07-13'}],
    'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:date'}, {'name': 'ga:dimension1'}, {'name': 'ga:dimension2'}, {'name': 'ga:userType'}, {'name': 'ga:landingpagePath'}, {'name': 'ga:deviceCategory'}],
    'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression': 'ga:bounces'}, {'expression': 'ga:goal1Completions'}]}]}
```

According to [the documentation on Google Analytics API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) on the pageToken parameter:

```
"A continuation token to get the next page of the results. Adding this to the request will return the rows after the pageToken. The pageToken should be the value returned in the nextPageToken parameter in the response to the reports.batchGet request. "
```

My understanding is that I need to query the API in chunks of 10,000 (max query result size allowed) and that to do this I must pass the value of nextPageToken field returned in each query result into the new query.

In researching, it sounds like the nextPageToken field will be a empty string when all the results have been returned.

So, I tried a while loop. To get to the loop stage I built some functions:

```
## generates the dimensions in the right format to use in the query
def generate_dims(dims):
    dims_ar = []
    for i in dims:
        d = {'name': i}
        dims_ar.append(d)
    return(dims_ar)

## generates the metrics in the right format to use in the query
def generate_metrics(mets):
    mets_ar = []
    for i in mets:
        m = {'expression': i}
        mets_ar.append(m)
    return(mets_ar)

## generate the query dict
def query(pToken, dimensions, metrics, start, end):
    api_query = {
            'reportRequests': [
                    {'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                     'pageToken': pToken,          
                     'pageSize': 10000,
                     'samplingLevel': 'LARGE',
                     'dateRanges': [{'startDate': start, 'endDate': end}],
                     'dimensions': generate_dims(dimensions),
                     'metrics': generate_metrics(metrics)
                     }]
    }
    return(api_query)
```

Example output of the above 3 functions:

```
sessions1_qr = query(pToken = pageToken,
                     dimensions = ['ga:date', 'ga:dimension1', 'ga:dimension2',
                                   'ga:userType', 'ga:landingpagePath',
                                   'ga:deviceCategory'],
                     metrics = ['ga:sessions', 'ga:bounces', 'ga:goal1Completions'],
                     start = '2018-06-01',
                     end = '2018-07-13')
```

The results of this look like the first code block in this post.

So far so good. Here's the loop I attempted:

```
def main(query):
    global pageToken, store_response

    # debugging, was hoping to see print output on each iteration (I didn't)
    print(pageToken)

    while pageToken != "":
        analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
        response = get_report(analytics, query)
        pageToken = response['reports'][0]['nextPageToken'] # < IT ALL COMES DOWN TO THIS LINE HERE
        store_response['pageToken'] = response

    return(False) # don't actually need the function to return anything, just append to global store_response.
```

Then I tried to run it:

```
pageToken = "go" # can be any string to get started
store_response = {}
sessions1 = main(sessions1_qr)
```

The following happens:

- The console remains busy
- The line `print(pageToken)` print's once to the console, the initial value of pageToken
- store_response dict has one item in it, not many as was hoped for

So, it looks like my loop runs once only.

Having stared at the code I suspect it has something to do with the value of query parameter that I pass to `main()`. When I initially call `main()` the value of query is the same as the first code block above (variable sessions1_qr, the dict with all the API call parameters). On each loop iteration this is supposed to update so that the value of pageToken is replaced with the responses nextPageToken value.

Put another way and in short, I need to update the input of the loop with a result from the previous iteration of the loop. My logic is clearly flawed so any help very much appreciated.

Adding some screen shots per comments discussion:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I assume that `query` (in `get_report(analytics, query)`) needs to be updated with `nextPageToken` to get the next page of the report. Where is that happening?

Comment: How are you calling `main`?

Comment: @ialarmedalien right, that's my issue. Presumably ```query``` is not being updated on each iteration and I'm not sure how best to do that?

Comment: @HenryWoody I don't understand, can you clarify?

Comment: Yeah, what does the line look like where you call `main`? More specifically what is the argument that you pass into `main` when you call it?

Comment: actually, I'd just alter the query data structure directly -- `query['reportRequests'][0]['pageToken'] = response['reports'][0]['nextPageToken']` since that's the only bit that is changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach I would take to solve this:

```
def main(query):
    global pageToken, store_response

    while pageToken != "":
        # debugging, was hoping to see print output on each iteration (I didn't)
        print(pageToken)
        analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
        response = get_report(analytics, query)

        # note that this has changed -- you were using 'pageToken' as a key
        # which would overwrite each response
        store_response[pageToken] = response

        pageToken = response['reports'][0]['nextPageToken'] # update the pageToken
        query['reportRequests'][0]['pageToken'] = pageToken # update the query


    return(False) # don't actually need the function to return anything, just append to global store_response.
```

i.e. update the query data structure manually, and store each of the responses with the `pageToken` as the dictionary key.

Presumably the last page has `''` as the `nextPageToken` so your loop will stop.

Comment: Thanks, I think we're close but I'm getting this error with your code block ```File "<ipython-input-24-f0a987da1ea1>", line 14, in main
    pageToken = response['reports'][0]['nextPageToken'] # update the pageToken

KeyError: 'nextPageToken```

Comment: can you dump the structure of the response to make sure that `response['reports'][0]['nextPageToken']` is the correct position for `nextPageToken`?

Comment: Sure but how do I do that?! (I've migrated over to Python from r just in the past few days)

Comment: just use a `print` statement -- `print( reponse['reports'][0] )`

Comment: In case you haven't seen it, the [python docs for built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) have lots of useful info for navigating different data structures.

Comment: Easier if I show just the bottom of it (where the nextPageToken) part is since it's a large set of data: ```that-misrepresent-depression-(and-get-it-right)', 'tablet'], 'metrics': [{'values': ['1', '0', '0']}]}], 'totals': [{'values': ['107278', '45084', '0']}], 'rowCount': 107278, 'minimums': [{'values': ['0', '0', '0']}], 'maximums': [{'values': ['1', '1', '0']}], 'isDataGolden': True}, 'nextPageToken': '10000'}```, also adding a screen shot of original post from within spyder variable explorer after drilling down into ```response['reports'][0]```

Comment: I thin it might be that because on the last iteration of the loop the API does not provide a nextPageToken variable

Comment: I got this working and would not have if not for your help here, so thank you. I changed ```pageToken = response['reports'][0]['nextPageToken'] # update the pageToken``` to ```pageToken = response['reports'][0].get('nextPageToken') # update the pageToken``` and in my while loop changed to ```while pageToken != "" and pageToken != None:```